# extract signed data from pkcs7 in python

Tags: python, openssl, x509, pem, pkcs#7

i have a usb cryptotoken and able to sign data and pack it in pkcs file. then i can extract certificate and data from that file using openssl as follows:

```
openssl cms -verify -in signature.p7s -inform DER -noverify -outform DER -signer cert.pem -out textdata
```

so my question is how to do the same using python (pyopenssl)?

i've tried to do as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123106/pyopenssl-to-verify-the-file-signature), but there is different case - i have attached signature and do not have separate signature and certificate file - i have ASN.1 encoded file, which contains as certificates as data and signature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several hurdles to overcome to achieve what you are looking for.

First, the `pyopenssl` binding itself is  limited when it comes to its `crypto` module, where you desired functionality resides. In fact, [the `pyopenssl crypto` documentation](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html) states:
[image]
The [`pyca/cryptography`](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) module mentioned is exposed via two internal attributes of the `pyopenssl crypto` module, with the names `_lib` and `_ffi`, which need to be used to get to the required functionality.

Then the `CMS_verify()` function that would be your logical choice for this is not included in the `pyca/cryptography` bindings either. However, for your purpose it is probably good enough to use `PKCS7_verify()` -- you can read all about that in a StackExchange question [OpenSSL PKCS#7 vs. S/MIME](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/41399/59016). The function [`crypto.load_pkcs7_data()`](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs7_data) comes in handy.

All that said, the following code snippet might do it for you -- although from your description it is not clear to me whether the certificate of the signer is included in the `.p7s` file (in that case you do not have to give `-signer` as an argument to `openssl cms -verify` like you did). It worked for me, so give it a try:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto
from OpenSSL._util import (
    ffi as _ffi,
    lib as _lib,
)

# Or, alternatively:
# from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
# _lib = Binding.lib
# _ffi = Binding.ffi

with open('message_der.p7s', 'rb') as f:
    p7data = f.read()
p7 = crypto.load_pkcs7_data(crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1, p7data)

bio_out =crypto._new_mem_buf()
res = _lib.PKCS7_verify(p7._pkcs7, _ffi.NULL, _ffi.NULL, _ffi.NULL, bio_out, _lib.PKCS7_NOVERIFY)
if res == 1:
    databytes = crypto._bio_to_string(bio_out)
    print(databytes)
else:
    errno = _lib.ERR_get_error()
    errstrlib = _ffi.string(_lib.ERR_lib_error_string(errno))
    errstrfunc = _ffi.string(_lib.ERR_func_error_string(errno))
    errstrreason = _ffi.string(_lib.ERR_reason_error_string(errno))
```

In case you decide to use this approach, here is [a caveat about using this OpenSSL bindings module directly](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/bindings/openssl/):
[image]

Comment: Correct answer to loading PKCS#7 file is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45111623/1548275

Comment: @JariTurkia In that answer I do not see where the actual signed data is extracted from the PKCS7 file and the signature verified, which was the question here. Interesting link to that `pyopenssl` pull request though, it does seem to fill the gap to get to the data.

Comment: Actually, in that answer there is a suggested `OpenSSL.crypto.load_pkcs7_data(type, buffer)` which does the trick of loading data. Given `OpenSSL.crypto.PKCS7` does not implement almost anything useful, the obvious next move is to extract the X.509 certificate. I spent a while attempting to get `PKCS7_verify()` working, but failed. As suggested in the other answer, getting the CData-pointer and reading X.509 certificate bytes there does work.

Comment: My answer here does show how to leverage `PKCS7_verify()`, did that not work for you?

Comment: Doing a `_lib.PKCS7_verify()` always returned 0. The error reason was "no data". I'm speculating, that PKCS7_verify() doesn't account for different types of PKCS#7 data: signed, enveloped or signed&enveloped.

Comment: That is weird. Did the `openssl cms -verify` command succeed with that same input though?

Comment: That would be a negative. This is not a S/MIME-case. It's a simple case of trying to extract X.509 out of PKCS#7-file.

Comment: So that explains why `PKCS7_verify()` returned "no data" in your case. But this question was about a case that the bundle _did_ contain data -- hence the `openssl cms -verify` command. By the way, PKCS#7 (or nowadays CMS) does not necessarily imply S/MIME, which is built on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

The Python code below (posted in [How to extract the signature from a p7s file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72970360/how-to-extract-the-signature-from-a-p7s-file)) will extract the cryptographic data you need, plus some (no protected/private arguments needed).

```
# Python 3.10 code to extract relevant data from a PKCS#7 signature file

from datetime import datetime
from asn1crypto import cms
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7

# these are the components we are going to extract
payload: bytes                      # the original payload
signature: bytes                    # the digital signature
signature_algorithm: str            # the algorithm used to generate the signature
signature_timestamp: datetime       # the signature's timestamp
payload_hash: bytes                 # the payload hash
hash_algorithm: str                 # the algorithm used to calculate the payload hash
cert_chain: list[x509.Certificate]  # the X509 certificate chain

# define the PKCS#7 signature file path here
p7s_filepath: str = 'my_signature_file_path.p7s'

# load the p7s file
with open(p7s_filepath, 'rb') as f:
    p7s_bytes: bytes = f.read()
    f.close()

# extract the certificater chain
cert_chain = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(p7s_bytes)

# extract the needed structures
content_info: cms.ContentInfo = cms.ContentInfo.load(p7s_bytes)
signed_data: cms.SignedData = content_info['content']
signer_info: cms.SignerInfo = signed_data['signer_infos'][0]

# extract the payload (None if payload is detached)
payload = signed_data['encap_content_info']['content'].native

# extract the remaining components
signature = signer_info['signature'].native
signature_algorithm = signer_info['signature_algorithm']['algorithm'].native
hash_algorithm = signer_info['digest_algorithm']['algorithm'].native

signed_attrs = signer_info['signed_attrs']
for signed_attr in signed_attrs:
    match signed_attr['type'].native:
        case 'message_digest':
            payload_hash = signed_attr['values'][0].native
        case 'signing_time':
            signature_timestamp = signed_attr['values'][0].native
```