# How to extract the signature from a p7s file?

Tags: python, cryptography, pkcs#7, pyopenssl, asn1crypto

I need the Python code to extract from the p7s file the signature resulting from digitally signing a document, in both situations where the payload is inside of, and external to, the p7s file. I have tried several crypto packages (PyOpenSSL, PyCripto, Cryptography, ASN1Crypto, and a few others), to no avail. I am able to extract basically everything else (certificates, payload, signature timestamp, etc.), but not the encrypted digest (the signature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Python 3.10 code to extract relevant data from a PKCS#7 signature file

from datetime import datetime
from asn1crypto import cms
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs7

# these are the components we are going to extract
payload: bytes                      # the original payload
signature: bytes                    # the digital signature
signature_algorithm: str            # the algorithm used to generate the signature
signature_timestamp: datetime       # the signature's timestamp
payload_hash: bytes                 # the payload hash
hash_algorithm: str                 # the algorithm used to calculate the payload hash
cert_chain: list[x509.Certificate]  # the X509 certificate chain

# define the PKCS#7 signature file path here
p7s_filepath: str = 'my_signature_file_path.p7s'

# load the p7s file
with open(p7s_filepath, 'rb') as f:
    p7s_bytes: bytes = f.read()
    f.close()

# extract the certificater chain
cert_chain = pkcs7.load_der_pkcs7_certificates(p7s_bytes)

# extract the needed structures
content_info: cms.ContentInfo = cms.ContentInfo.load(p7s_bytes)
signed_data: cms.SignedData = content_info['content']
signer_info: cms.SignerInfo = signed_data['signer_infos'][0]

# extract the payload (None if payload is detached)
payload = signed_data['encap_content_info']['content'].native

# extract the remaining components
signature = signer_info['signature'].native
signature_algorithm = signer_info['signature_algorithm']['algorithm'].native
hash_algoritmo = signer_info['digest_algorithm']['algorithm'].native

signed_attrs = signer_info['signed_attrs']
for signed_attr in signed_attrs:
    match signed_attr['type'].native:
        case 'message_digest':
            payload_hash = signed_attr['values'][0].native
        case 'signing_time':
            signature_timestamp = signed_attr['values'][0].native
```